# Ignore columns in MySQL query result with null values

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a MySql table as,

```
Name    Month           Salary
=======================================
A   Salary_Month_Sept   15000
A   Salary_Month_Oct    0
B   Salary_Month_Sept   12000
B   Salary_Month_Oct    0
C   Salary_Month_Sept   13000
C   Salary_Month_Oct    0
```

and I am querying that table as

```
select Name,
    max(IF(Month = 'Salary_Month_Sept', Salary, 0)) AS 'Salary_Month_Sept',
    max(IF(Month = 'Salary_Month_Oct', Salary, 0)) AS 'Salary_Month_Oct'
from myTable
```

Which returns the query result as

```
Name    Salary_Month_Sept   Salary_Month_Oct
=============================================
A       15000               0
B       12000               0
C       17000               0
```

How can i ignore the column containing only zero or null values from the above query result.

Comment: There is no "escaping". A database is there to store the data, not to format it nicely. Do this on application layer.

Comment: I mean ignoring that column in query results

Comment: Yes, I understood that right. My comment still stands. If you don't want it in your result, don't select it. Simple as that.

Comment: Please see the edited question with base table and returning query

Comment: Also the `max(if))` condition is generating dynamically within stored procedure using `group_concat`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use *. Name columns you want to have. The query is not a crystal ball. It doesn't know in front if there will be data for the column. To do something like that you need 2 queries, assuming the salaries are only positive:

1. Select sum(salary_sept), sum(salary_oct), ... for the condition you need.
2. Create second select only for columns returning sum bigger than zero.

The SQL has no time machine, sorry. You have to do your work yourself.